# »Ojalá« + subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo, adverbios

Estuve pensando en esta construcción para interpretar sus significados. Por ejemplo:

> 1. Ojalá **digas** eso.
> 2. Ojalá **dijeras** eso.
> 3. Ojalá **hubieses dicho** eso.

En las tres formas tenemos el subjuntivo en presente, pretérito y pluscuamperfecto.
Entiendo las dos últimas como *ojalá dijeras eso = no lo dices*, *ojalá hubieses dicho eso = no lo dijiste*. ¿Cómo interpreto la primera?

Comment: El presente del subjuntivo deja abierta la posibilidad de decir la cosa. En n.° 2, no lo dices y punto. Pero en n.° 1, no lo *has* dicho, mas todavía *puedes*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Deseo que lo digas en el futuro

> Ojalá que cuando me case digas que te da gusto

2. Deseo que lo digas en el presente o futuro (probablemente un hecho recurrente)

> Ojalá que cuando preparo la comida dijeras que te gustó

3. Deseo que lo dijeras en el pasado, cuando no lo hiciste

> Ojalá que cuando murió la Tia María hubieses dicho que lo sentías