# Usage of "ojalá + que" or "ojalá"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales

In Latin America, I hear *ojalá* used mostly by itself as an exclamation, but sometimes in a sentence: `Ojalá + que + subjunctive verb`. For example:

> Ojalá que yo sepa la respuesta

In Spain, I hear *ojalá* used both as an exclamation and in a sentence: `Ojalá + imperfect subjunctive verb`. (no conjunction "que"). For example:

> Ojalá yo supiera la respuesta

Is this an accurate comparison of uses of Spanish in these two places?

Comment: You may find ["Ojalá" + subjuntivo](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16345/ojal%c3%a1-subjuntivo) useful. What is explained there applies to all dialects of Spanish. I don't think there's any difference from a country to another.

Comment: I recommend you to read http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/913/is-there-a-difference-between-espa%C3%B1ol-and-castellano It has nothing to do with the main subject of your question but it really helps undestand things better when you talk about "español" and "castellano". I specially like @CesarGon answer.

Comment: I think the _que_ is optional just as English _that_ in _he told me [that] he was going home tomorrow_

Answer (score 4):

*ojalá* is basically the *I wish* structure in English.
We can use the present and imperfect subjunctive. When using the former, we're expecting for something to happen in a certain future. When using the latter, the expectation is focused on the present:

> Ojalá no **lloviera** = Espero que no suceda hoy.
>   Ojalá no **llueva** = Espero que no suceda mañana o el resto de la semana.

Other option includes the pluperfect past subjunctive like *ojalá + hubiese/hubiera + past participle*; its implication remains in the past. (I didn't happen.)

> Ojalá **hubiese traído** mi paraguas = But I didn't.

*ojalá que* is also used but not often as the plain *ojalá*.

Comment: You may add it comes from an Arabic expression meaning _may Allah/God wish (that)_

Comment: Does the structure: "Ojalá que..." work also?

Comment: @sbswim Yes, but it's often omitted.

Comment: @Ustanak, edit that last comment into the answer: the usage of _que_ is part of the question

Comment: "Ojalá no lloviera" means that it is currently raining, and you wish it weren't.

Answer (score 0):

With "ojalá" the "que" is optional:

Ojalá llueva / 
Ojalá que llueva

Comment: I think that the question is not really about the "que" but about the verb tense used. The question is really if there is a difference between `Ojala llueva / Ojala que llueva` and "Ojala lloviese/ Ojala que lloviese".

Comment: Thank you, Diego. I only addressed the title of the question. To address the last part of the question: I am a Latin America Spanish speaking native and I can tell you that you are correct. You will hear "Ojala" as an expression or used with the subjunctive.   I would say by itself it can be translated as "God willing" or " I hope so." Within a sentence with "que" you can translated as "One hopes that" and without "que" it can be translated as "hopefully."

Comment: Your comment still does not answer the question of which tense to use though.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, mdewey. Yes, you hear it either way, present or imperfect subjunctive, however, the present subjunctive denotes more hope than the more elusive "supiera," as if the goal was even further than the more attainable "sepa."

Comment: "Ojala yo sepa la respuesta." gives the impression that he/she may have an idea of what the answer is, however, may not be the correct one.                                 "Ojala yo supiera la respuesta." sounds like the speaker may not even have a vague idea of what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Me permito contestar tu respuesta, porque como hablante hispano de nacimiento, entiendo la pequeña diferencia en contexto que ambas expresiones suponen.

Si bien es cierto, ambas dan aparentemente el mismo sentido, se infieren contextos un poco diferentes.

**Ojalá que yo sepa la respuesta** se usa en una situación donde estás pensando en algo que vas a hacer en el futuro. Aún no estás presentando ese examen, pero esperas prepararte lo suficiente para que llegado el momento, sepas la respuesta.

Por ejemplo, "*Ojalá que yo sepa las respuestas en el examen de mañana*".

**Ojalá yo supiera la respuesta** se usa en cualquier situación actual o futura. Y es más una expresión que indica que en este momento deseas algo porque en realidad pasa lo contrario.

Por ejemplo, "*Ojalá que yo supiera lo que tengo que hacer para bajar de peso*".

en ambos casos, que y yo son opcionales. tiene tanto sentido decir

"ojalá *que yo* supiera" como "ojalá *yo* supiera", "ojalá *que* supiera" y "ojalá supiera". todos me hacen el mismo sentido. también lo mismo para "ojalá *que yo* sepa", se vale igual "ojalá *yo* sepa", "ojalá *que* sepa" y "ojalá sepa".

Espero haber sido claro en los contextos que implican ambas formas.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked it up on duolingo:

When there is to translate ''if only'' you should use ''ojala'' and subj. imprefect:

If only i knew the answer = Ojala que supiera la respuesta

When there is ''hopefully'' you should use ''ojala que'' and subj. present:

Hopefully i('ll) know the answer = Ojala que sepa la respuesta

Comment: my bad: ojala supiera la respuesta (without que)